# How do you use MultiplyNumeric for a date transformed to a weight and a value of the same table?

Tags: python, featuretools

My primary aim is a feature which considers more recent information of higher value.

So, the Idea is to calculate via a new primitive transformation "WeightTimeUntil" a weighing factor which afterwards could be used by the transformation primitive "MultiplyNumeric" to get weighted values.

I used the walkthrough [walkthrough](https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/automated-feature-engineering/tree/master/walk_through) of Will Koehrsen as a starting point for data and the entity setup.

Thereby I ran into following problem:

1. featuretools have not choosen the combination I intended to achieve (see below)
2. it looks like featuretools did not choose the combination because of type miss match?!
3. by changing the type of the value I wanted to be multiply by the weighting factor I managed to get the right combination but not for the right target
4. for target equal client, featuretools have not choosen the combination I intended to get at all. Only when I use the target equal loans where the date and the value are columns of, featuretools used the right combination

here is the code for the "WeightTimeUntil" primitive

```py
def weight_time_until(array, time):
    diff = pd.DatetimeIndex(array) - time
    s = np.floor(diff.days/365/0.5)
    aWidth = 9
    a = math.log(0.1) / ( -(aWidth -1) )

    w = np.exp(-a*s) 

    return w


    WeightTimeUntil = make_trans_primitive(function=weight_time_until,
                                 input_types=[Datetime],
                                 return_type=Numeric,
                                 uses_calc_time=True,
                                 description="Calculates weight time until the cutoff time",
                                 name="weight_time_until")
```

here is the DFS execution code:

```py
features, feature_names = ft.dfs(entityset = es, target_entity = 'clients', 
                                 agg_primitives = ['sum'],
                                 trans_primitives = [WeightTimeUntil, MultiplyNumeric])
```

and here the list of features:

```
 <Feature: income>,
 <Feature: credit_score>,
 <Feature: join_month>,
 <Feature: log_income>,
 <Feature: SUM(loans.loan_amount)>,
 <Feature: SUM(loans.rate)>,
 <Feature: SUM(payments.payment_amount)>,
 <Feature: WEIGHT_TIME_UNTIL(joined)>,
 <Feature: join_month * log_income>,
 <Feature: income * log_income>,
 <Feature: income * join_month>,
 <Feature: credit_score * join_month>,
 <Feature: credit_score * log_income>,
 <Feature: credit_score * income>,
 <Feature: SUM(loans.WEIGHT_TIME_UNTIL(loan_start))>,
 <Feature: SUM(loans.WEIGHT_TIME_UNTIL(loan_end))>,
 <Feature: SUM(loans.loan_amount * rate)>,
 <Feature: income * SUM(loans.loan_amount)>,
 <Feature: credit_score * SUM(loans.loan_amount)>,
 <Feature: log_income * SUM(payments.payment_amount)>,
 <Feature: log_income * WEIGHT_TIME_UNTIL(joined)>,
 <Feature: income * SUM(payments.payment_amount)>,
 <Feature: join_month * SUM(loans.rate)>,
 <Feature: income * SUM(loans.rate)>,
 <Feature: join_month * SUM(loans.loan_amount)>,
 <Feature: SUM(loans.rate) * SUM(payments.payment_amount)>,
 <Feature: credit_score * WEIGHT_TIME_UNTIL(joined)>,
 <Feature: SUM(loans.rate) * WEIGHT_TIME_UNTIL(joined)>,
 <Feature: income * WEIGHT_TIME_UNTIL(joined)>,
 <Feature: log_income * SUM(loans.loan_amount)>,
 <Feature: SUM(loans.loan_amount) * WEIGHT_TIME_UNTIL(joined)>,
 <Feature: SUM(loans.loan_amount) * SUM(payments.payment_amount)>,
 <Feature: credit_score * SUM(loans.rate)>,
 <Feature: log_income * SUM(loans.rate)>,
 <Feature: credit_score * SUM(payments.payment_amount)>,
 <Feature: SUM(payments.payment_amount) * WEIGHT_TIME_UNTIL(joined)>,
 <Feature: join_month * WEIGHT_TIME_UNTIL(joined)>,
 <Feature: SUM(loans.loan_amount) * SUM(loans.rate)>,
 <Feature: join_month * SUM(payments.payment_amount)>
```

I expected something like this:

```
SUM(loans.loan_amount * loans.WEIGHT_TIME_UNTIL(loan_start))>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `SUM(loans.loan_amount * loans.WEIGHT_TIME_UNTIL(loan_start))>` is a depth 3 feature since you are stacking `Sum`, `MultiplyNumeric`, and `WeightTimeUntil`. You can read more about depth in the documentation [here](https://docs.featuretools.com/automated_feature_engineering/afe.html#creating-deep-features).

You can fix this by increasing the allowed depth in your call to dfs like this

```
features, feature_names = ft.dfs(entityset = es, target_entity = 'clients', 
                                 agg_primitives = ['sum'],
                                 max_depth=3,
                                 trans_primitives = [WeightTimeUntil, MultiplyNumeric])
```

The alternative way to do it, is to provide your feature as a seed feature, which don't get counted towards the max depth. You can do that like this

```
seed_features=[ft.Feature(es["loans"]["loan_start"], primitive=WeightTimeUntil)]

features, feature_names = ft.dfs(entityset = es, target_entity = 'clients', 
                                 agg_primitives = ['sum'],
                                 seed_features=seed_features,
                                 trans_primitives = [MultiplyNumeric])
```

The second approach my be preferable since it will create the feature you want, but fewer features overall.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the feature SUM(loans.loan_amount * WEIGHT_TIME_UNTIL(loan_start)) I wanted!!!